# Getting 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop' warning despite having key in parent element

Tags: reactjs

I'm still getting 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop'  warning in React, but I have added a unique id key to the parent element so can't work it out!

I tried passing the task.id as props to the TaskCard component but that didn't fix the issue either.

This is my Task component:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <Row>
      {tasks.filter((task) => !task.complete).map((task) => (
        <Col key={task.id} sm={2}>
          <TaskCard
            task={task}
            handleTaskComplete={handleTaskComplete}
            handleDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask}
          />
        </Col>
      ))}
   </Row>
 </div>
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code looks good, so I can only suggest two things. 1) verify that you're code has rebuilt/you're using the newest version in the browser. 2) verify that the error is talking about **this specific list**. It may be catching a missing key somewhere else (you can test it by removing the list here and seeing if the error goes away)

Comment: So, dumb question, but did you verify that the ids in your tasks are actually unique?

Comment: What is `tasks`, can you add it's definition to the question?